# How to append content to tabel with ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I need some help concerning the append call in javascript.

I have the following table in my view :

```
<div class="splitcontentleft">
  <table class="list user_roles">
  .........
  </table>
</div>
```

How should I call here the append command in my ***.js.erb** file?

I do the following:

```
$('#user_roles_table').append('<%= @roles %>');
```

But it didn't work. I also tested the append command at a other div tag and that works, so I reckon the failure is the pramater '#user_roles_table', or not?

Comment: have look to jQuery selector http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#user_roles_table')
```

tells jquery to wrap an object with the id attribute "user_roles_table". You probably want to use

```
$('table.user_roles')
```

which says select an element with tag table AND a class attribute of "user_roles" or just

```
$('.user_roles')
```

if that element is the only one with that class and you're not reusing the classnames.

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for an exhaustive list of the selectors you can use with jquery